# How to update each row sequentially based on the last row in a single SQL statement?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

My SQL knowledge is limited and I'm not sure how to even phrase this question to find some answers.

My problem is: I have a database full of candlestick objects:

```
class Candle(Base):
    __tablename__ = "candle"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    pool_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('pool.id'), index=True, nullable=False)
    type = Column(String(2), nullable=False, index=True)
    timestamp = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    open = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    low = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    high = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    close = Column(Float, nullable=False)
```

Currently there are 4.1M candles in the database but I've found a bug in the system:
The "open" property has to be exactly the same as the "close" property of the last existing candle (based on the timestamp) but currently that is not the case. I have to also respect their type ('1M', '1H', '1D') and pool_id (which there are thousands of).

Normally I would do this using Python and load candles for pool and type, check them one by one and update the ones that don't have equal values, but since the DB is now large, it would take a very long time. Our DB is in AWS and even if we ran it from there it would take a couple of days.

How can I write an SQL query (or a set of SQL queries) that would go through the candles one by one and check if the previous "close" is the same as current "open", and if not, updated them to make that true?

Any help very appreciated!

Edit: example data

| id | pool_id | type | timestamp | open | low | high | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25095 | 1M | 1642592640 | 0.7723 | 0.7723 | 0.7806 | **0.7732** |
| 2 | 25095 | 1M | 1642592700 | **0.7813** | 0.7557 | 0.7813 | 0.7813 |

As you can see, first candle close is **0.7732** but next candle open is **0.7813**

For this example, the second candle values should be:

**open: 0.7732**, low: 0.7557, high: 0.7813 close: 0.7813.

edit 2:
my idea of the sql would be:

```
UPDATE candle
SET open = LAG(close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY type, pool_id ORDER BY timestamp)
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id 
  FROM candle c 
  WHERE c.open != LAG(c.close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY type, pool_id ORDER BY timestamp)
);
```

Comment: "one by one" (aka rbar, row by agonizing row) is not how to do things in sql, sql is used on sets. As for your problem, please add some sample data to illustrate the issue

Comment: What does "previous" mean?  Are you going by the row number in the database, or by timestamp ordering?

Comment: Added a screenshot to clarify - previous candle means previous by timestamp with the same pool_id and type

Comment: If the open/close of two records don't match, how do you know which one is correct?

Comment: Candles are created from records that are made of a timestamp and price - thanks to this I can be sure that "close" values are always correct - I simply need to make sure that the "open" of candle is always equal to the "close" of last candle

Comment: That makes no sense, I can't see how the timestamp/price combination makes the close value any more correct then the open value. Whatever is supplying the values is working correctly across all the values or it is not.

Comment: It is irrelevant to the question, but timestamp/price records are being added sequentially, then combined into a candle based on their ids: first price is open, last price is close.
To make the candle true, i also need to the first record to be "fake" - just the last available instead of the new price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit 2 query is conceptually very close, However, there are 2 flaws:

1. Window functions (here lag) cannot be used in the `where` clause.
   This stems from Window functions being the last phase processed
   except the final sort. So by time to execute the Window function the
   `where` clause is long over with. Google *SQL Order of Operations*
   for more.
2. When using the `update ... from` structure you **should not repeat**
   the table name being updated.

Correcting for these results in: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b4620e677bd07d33d6de09cf1b837380))

```
    with cdata(candle_id, prior_close) as 
         (select  candle_id, lag(close, 1) over (partition by type, pool_id order by ephoc_tm) 
            from  candles
         ) --select * from cdata; 
    update candles c
       set open = cd.prior_close
         , updated_ts = now()
      from cdata cd
     where c.candle_id = cd.candle_id 
       and cd.prior_close is not null
       and cd.prior_close is distinct from c.open;
```

Cautions: (At least IMHO)

- Using a column name `timestamp` is  a poor practice because it it a
  Postgres data type. Using data types as column names leads to
  confusion. Especially, when the column `timestamp` is not a timestamp
  data type.
- Be cautious for column names `open` and `close`. While they are not
  reserved words for Postgres, they are reserved words in the SQL
  Standard.

Note: For demo I user `ephoc_tm` instead of timestamp for column name. Also included additional test rows. I never trust a test with essentially a single item nor in which all cases meet the criteria being tested.

Comment: can you explain "updated_ts = now()"? what does that line do?

Comment: also, you said "see demo" but i can't find any links
much appreciated response though!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the link. See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b4620e677bd07d33d6de09cf1b837380). The update_ts was just adding a timestamp for demo purpose only to visually the rows in updated. This **would not** be in your actual final query, but might be useful for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, LAG(close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY type, pool_id ORDER BY timestamp) prev_close
    FROM candle
)
UPDATE c
SET c.open = c2.prev_close, 
    c.low = LEAST(c2.prev_close, c.open, c.low, c.high, c.close), 
    c.high = GREATEST(c2.prev_close, c.open, c.low, c.high, c.close)
FROM candle c
JOIN cte c2
ON c.id = c2.id
WHERE c2.prev_close IS NOT NULL
AND c.open != c2.prev_close;
```